# How to fill a tabe automatically with a procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a very big table for users as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `karbar` (
 `uid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `email` varchar(70) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `password` char(41) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `token` char(40) NOT NULL,
 `joined` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `totalspam` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `flname` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `activation_link` char(40) NOT NULL,
 `role` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `gender` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'u',
 `is_shop_active` char(0) DEFAULT '',
 `english_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `followings` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
 `followers` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I want to fill this table with lots of data. Let's say millions of records. How to do this? I need to produce unique emails. Different data for emails. I know I can use `CONCAT` but don't know how to produce random data

Comment: So you need to fill those fileds with random data ?

Comment: @Up_One, Your comment really helped ;-) I'm looking for a procedure to do that for me. How to write a procedure to complete this task?

Comment: Why inventing the wheel ? "nothing is created everything is copied" kkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got your answer ! 
Go to [Talend](http://www.talend.com/download) download page and download the Talend Open Studio for Data Integration. Is free and uses Java to work. 
After you downladed and installed talend go to this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSAEXtAsQ-Y) to see how to generate what ever you need for free 
 I am using Talend for stress testing and ETL process 
You can throw the generated data mysql directly or into a CVS file and then load it into the mysql table !

Answer (score 0):

An easy php based web application to produce very realistic data to populate your table.

Its online site has limitation, but if you download the source code and install it on your PC then you can generate every kind of data that you want.
It supports csv,sql,html,etc file formats.

[image]

[Data generator for Oracle,MySQL,Postgres,SQL lite and more](http://www.generatedata.com/)